# Calculation of median

Tags: statistics, median

I want to calculate the median of several variables. The detail is as follow:
For example, a, b and c are all random number from uniform distribution in certain range (different between each other). Then, if D=a*b*c, and I want to know what's the median value of D.

Any method to do this? Please let me know. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

For a continuous probability distribution on $\left[a,b\right]$,
the median is a number $x\in\left[a,b\right]$ s.t.
$$
\int_{a}^{x}f\left(x\right)dx=1/2.
$$
That is, the probability of the random variable $X<x$ is equal to
that of $X>x$. Plug in the product distribution and solve the above.